# An integral related to the derivative of Legendre polynomials

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions

I want to calculate the integral 
$$
I=\int_{-1}^{1}
\Big(\frac{\mathrm{d}P_{n+1}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\Big)
\Big(\frac{\mathrm{d}P_{m+1}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\Big)
\mathrm{d}t
$$
where $P_n(t)$ is [Legendre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials). By virtue of the identity
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}P_{n+1}(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}=2\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}\frac{P_{n-2k}(t)}{\vert\vert P_{n-2k}(t)\vert\vert^2}
$$
where ${\vert\vert P_{n}(t)\vert\vert}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{2n+1}}$, and Using the property of [Double Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleSeries.html), then
$$
I=4\int_{-1}^{1}
\Big(\sum_{k_1=0}^{[n/2]}\frac{P_{n-2k_1}(t)}{\vert\vert P_{n-2k_1}(t)\vert\vert^2}\Big)
\Big(\sum_{k_2=0}^{[m/2]}\frac{P_{m-2k_2}(t)}{\vert\vert P_{m-2k_2}(t)\vert\vert^2}\Big)
\mathrm{d}t\\
=4\sum_{k_1=0}^{[n/2]}\sum_{k_2=0}^{[m/2]}
\frac{1}{\vert\vert P_{n-2k_1}(t)\vert\vert^2}
\frac{1}{\vert\vert P_{m-2k_2}(t)\vert\vert^2}
\int_{-1}^{1}{P_{n-2k_1}(t)}{P_{m-2k_2}(t)}\mathrm{d}t\\
=4\sum_{k_1=0}^{[n/2]}\sum_{k_2=0}^{[m/2]}
\frac{1}{\vert\vert P_{n-2k_1}(t)\vert\vert^2}
\delta_{n-2k_1,m-2k_2}\\
$$

If $n=m$, then
$$
I=4\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}\frac{1}{\vert\vert P_{n-2k}(t)\vert\vert^2}
 =2\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}\big(2(n-2k)+1\big)\\
 =2([n/2]+1)\big((2n+1)-2[n/2]\big)
 =(n+1)(n+2)
$$

But if $n\neq m$, How can I move on?

Comment: Your approach works also for $n\neq m$. Just assume (without loss of generality), that $n\leq m$. From the Kronecker $\delta$ you can also read off that $m-n$ must be even. Since the Kronecker $\delta$ in the last double sum simply picks out one $k_{2}$, but the summand does not depend on $k_{2}$, the result is valid for any $n$, $m$ that obey the restrictions, I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Legendre polynomials are orthogonal.[here](http://physicspages.com/2011/03/18/legendre-polynomials-orthogonality/) So it may work to calculate that integral by using integrating by parts twices.

Comment: I know. But a two order derivative will be involved.